# Center and put multiple items on the same line using Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I want to put a `Label` and an `Entry` widgets on the same line and center them.

I saw on multiple posts that to center, `pack()` method was easier. But, to put on the same line, it's `grid()`.

With `grid()`, I suppose I have to build all the layout, then center it. Is there a way to do it on the go? With `pack()`, I don't have any idea.

But, I want to do both at the same time. I didn't find any answer :/
If someone can help me, I will be very grateful!

Comment: Put the label and the entry in a frame and use `pack()` on the frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to put everything in a frame and pack() the frame.

Thanks to @acw1668